# Yosef Bones out of Egypt

Tags: death, yetziat-mitzrayim, yosef

What Happened to Yosef Bones when the Took them out of Egypt ot actually when the Found them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Bavli*, *Sota* 13, says (if I understand it correctly):

> Come, see how beloved commands were to *Moshe rabenu*, for all the Jews were busy with spoils and he was busy with commands [specifically, filling the promise of taking *Yosef*'s bones, see the beginning of *B'shalach* —msh210], as it says "a wisehearted person will take commands...".
> And how did *Moshe rabenu* know where *Yosef* was buried? They said, *Serach* the daughter of *Asher* was left from that generation; *Moshe* went to her and said to her "do you know where *Yosef*'s buried?". She told him, "the Egyptians made him a metal coffin and set it in the Nile River so its waters would increase".
> *Moshe* went and stood on the Nile's bank and told him "*Yosef*, *Yosef*, the time that God has sworn 'I'm redeeming you' has come, and the oath you made the Jews swear has arrived. If you show yourself, good; otherwise, we're exempt from your oath". Immediately, *Yosef*'s coffin floated....
> Rabbi *Nasan* says, he was buried in a royal tomb. *Moshe* went and stood by the royal tomb and said "*Yosef*, the time that God has sworn 'I'm redeeming you' has come, and the oath you made the Jews swear has arrived. If you show yourself, good; otherwise, we're exempt from your oath". At that time, *Yosef*'s coffin shook. *Moshe* took it and brought it with him....

Answer (score 2):

The Tosfos Shantz (סוטה יג, א) says that they took the Bones of Yosef and placed it in the skin of a כבש (Goat I Think) the Animal then came alive with Yosef Bones in it and Thats why it says נוהג כצאן יוסף.

Comment: My question is it says that the Yam Suf split when it saw the Casket of Yosef which If you think it is not a Problem its a Machlokes Medrashim.Or maybe even they took the Casket separately and thats why it split